# Javascript - check Checkboxes does not work

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Recently I tried to get a small javascript to work, which shall only check some checkboxes. The problem is, I have no clue about Javascript and therefore I am a bit lost whilst looking at the google results.

So far I used a syntax checker I have found online which gave no errors (a good sign, but it's not working anyway).
To prevent you from asking, the submitted name of the checkboxes is right (;

This is my code so far, any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

```
function checkAll(name) {
var flag = 0;
//get all checkboxes with that name
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(name);

//look if the check all box is checked or not, set the flag
if (document.getElementByName('check_all').checked === true) {
    flag = 1;
}
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    //check the boxes or uncheck them
    if (flag == 1) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
    }
    else {
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `document.getElementByName` function to obtain a single element by name. You'll either need to change that to an ID and use:

```
if(document.getElementById('check_all').checked === true) {
    flag = 1;
}
```

Or use `document.getElementsByName('check_all')[0]` in place of `document.getElementByName('check_all')`. This assumes that there's only a single element on the page with the name `check_all`, though; if there are multiple you'll want to consider some other way of uniquely identifying them (such as IDs).

Comment: This is an awkward mistake, but thanks, your answer solved my problem, made my day Sir!